# Stacktrace in node using Coffeescript - line number not matching

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

In a project I'm using CoffeeScript for node but whenever it throws an error like this and I check the line it doesn't correspond to the actual line number in the coffeescript file. How can I fix this?

```
2015-05-29T09:35:09.793Z - error: [api] TypeError: Cannot call method 'logger' of undefined stack=TypeError: Cannot call method 'logger' of undefined
    at /path/path-api/src/plugins/file.coffee:286:32
    at /path/path-api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/query.js:159:5
    at Cursor.nextObject (/path/path-api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:742:5)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how I can get line number with error in coffeescript file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311579/how-i-can-get-line-number-with-error-in-coffeescript-file)

Comment: What version of Coffeescript are you using? I've had this problem too but it got better in recent (9-12 months ago) versions of Coffeescript. (Because they added sourcemaps in 1.6, I think)

Answer (score 0):

Coffeescript transpiles to Javascript which then is executed by Node.js. Since the transpiling of coffeescript with all its syntactic sugar and abbreviations generates javascript the code generated looks a lot different thus varying in length.

To make this a bit clearer look at this coffee code:

```
for a in x
  dosomethingTM()
```

Pretty simple, 2 lines of code. Compiling (Transpiling) this to JS (which will eventually be executed to Node.js) will result in this:

```
var a, i, len;

for (i = 0, len = x.length; i < len; i++) {
  a = x[i];
  dosomethingTM();
}
```

As you can see, the code looks a lot different and has much more lines of code. 
When debugging or printing out a stacktrace you will get the line number of the code executed - this being the JS code. In order to find the correct line of code within your coffeescript file you will need a bit of practice (and good structured code) and/or so called source maps. (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/?redirect_from_locale=de)

You can compile coffeescript with appropriate source maps: http://coffeescript.org/#source-maps